# c++: how to insert data to a struct member (struct located in vector)

Tags: c++, string, vector, struct

as you could see in the title, I am working on a vector of structs.

one of the struct members is **string word**.
when i am trying to enter data to this member in this way: **(*iv).word=temp_str;**, i get a runtime error.

```
while (is!=str1.end())
{
    if (((*is)!='-')&&((*is)!='.')&&((*is)!=',')&&((*is)!=';')&&((*is)!='?')&&((*is)!='!')&&((*is)!=':'))
    {
        temp_str.push_back(*is);
        ++is;
    }
    else
    {        
        (*iv).word=temp_str;
        ++iv;
        str1.erase(is);
        temp_str.clear();
    }
}
```

this may be the relevant code interval.

should say- word and temp_str are of string type.
iv is an iterator to the vector.

what is the right way to enter data into a struct member in this case?

Comment: Post some code where you assign temp_str

Comment: How do you initialize your vector ? how do you iterate the vector ? please provide relevant code snippets

Comment: @iammilind, noone is responsible for having born in a non English-speaking country.

Comment: `iv->word` is the same as `*(iv).word`, but a bit easier to read/type.

Comment: –1, completely insufficient error description. Minimal code missing. Error message missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iterator is probably invalid, otherwise it shouldn't be a problem assigning one string to another.

One problem is the line:

```
str1.erase(is);
```

This will invalidate `is`, you should probably change it to:

```
is = str1.erase(is);
```

What does `iv` point at? It seems like you would need to add something like:

```
while (is!=str1.end() && iv != something.end())
```

as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it is a problem with the iterator or allocating space for the vector. Here is what should work

```
#define N 10

struct myStruct
{
    int a;
    std::string str;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<myStruct>  myVector;
    myVector.resize(N); 
    std::vector<myStruct>::iterator itr;    
    for (itr = myVector.begin(); itr != myVector.end(); ++itr)
    {
        std::string tmp = getString();
        itr->str = tmp;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is your solution when the Vector size is not known?

Comment: Well, that really depends on what you want to do.. You can use vector's push_back method in a loop until you get an empty string or something that will indicate that you have finished.