# c++: vectorof structs

Tags: c++

i am using an empty vector of structs.

now, when i am entering data to one of the struct members, does it change the size of the vector?

if yes, how should i initialize the iterator?
i have a runtime error, and my guess is that my iterator is invalid.

some relevant code:

```
   struct wordstype
{
    string word;
    int counter_same;
    int counter_contained;
    int counter_same1;
};
 std::vector<wordstype>::iterator iv=vec1.begin();
string temp_str;
string::iterator is=str1.begin();

while (is!=str1.end())
{
    if (((*is)!='-')&&((*is)!='.')&&((*is)!=',')&&((*is)!=';')&&((*is)!='?')&&((*is)!='!')&&((*is)!=':'))
    {
        temp_str.push_back(*is);
        ++is;
    }
    else
    {        
        (*iv).word=temp_str;
        ++iv;
        str1.erase(is);
        temp_str.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++: how to insert data to a struct member (struct located in vector)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208367/c-how-to-insert-data-to-a-struct-member-struct-located-in-vector)

Comment: You should edit your original question instead of posting a new one!

Comment: Basically, get the data into wordsType and do vec1.push_back(wordsTypeObj); That's safe.

Comment: Also, the line `str1.erase(is)` invalidates the `is` iterator.

Comment: @MichaelWild: Well spotted, and the fix is simple: `is = str1.erase(is);`.

Comment: when i am erasing a character from string in the line                is = str1.erase(is);  does it moves the characters after the deleted one to a new position in the string? something else- this line sets is to the same position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing values of the struct members doesn't affect the size of the vector. You get a run-time error, because you're trying to access the first element of an **empty** vector.

Try this instead:

```
wordstype wt;       // create a new struct
wt.word = temp_str; // set its elements as desired
vec1.push_back(wt); // insert the new struct into the empty vector
```

Alternatively you can declare the vector as

```
vector<wordstype> vec1(1);
```

which would initialize it with size 1. Then your current code will work (somewhat).

Comment: "Then your current code will work" - until it increments `iv` and tries to access the second element.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Well, that's why I put a "somewhat" in parens -- one problem at a time though :) He hasn't even written the other bug yet.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access the contents of a vector element before it exists in the vector.

If `vec1.empty()` is `true`, there are no elements in the vector.

You need to create the new data in a separate instance of `wordstype`, then push it onto the vector.